# How to store a pair of ids that I can check if I stored it already?

Tags: c#

I have the following problem:

I have pairs of Ids like:

```
1 3
3 1
1 2
...
```

Then I want to store it in some structure, so that I can simply check if I have this connection already:
`1 3` is stored, so when I get `3 1` I will see that `1 3` exists and it will return exist.
Then I get `1 2` and I will get not exists because `1 2` or `2 1` is not stored.

How to implement this, or what would be a good structure for this?

Comment: dictionary key/value of <string, string> ?

Comment: You can sort ids and store sorted.

Comment: Use Dictionary  refer : http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
// You could turn this into a struct if you wanted.
public sealed class IdPair : IEquatable<IdPair>
{
    private readonly int first;
    private readonly int second;

    public int First { get { return first; } }
    public int Second { get { return second; } }

    public IdPair(int first, int second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // This is order-neutral.
        // Could use multiplication, addition etc instead - the point is
        // that {x, y}.GetHashCode() must equal {y, x}.GetHashCode()
        return first ^ second; 
    }

    public override bool Equals(object x)
    {
        return Equals(x as IdPair);
    }

    public bool Equals(IdPair other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return (first == other.first && second == other.second) ||
               (first == other.second && second == other.first);
    }
}
```

Then you just need a `HashSet<IdPair>`. It feels like this is a more natural approach than using a `Dictionary`, as you don't really have a single key - you just have a pair where both properties are equally key-like, and you're basically interested in an order-neutral equality of pairs.

Comment: Was thinking on the same lines, but thought of using struct or just a class. How is this better than using say a simple type like `public class IdPair`? Could you please explain?

Comment: @unlimit: This *is* a simple type like `public class IdPair` - it just implements `IEquatable<IdPair>` for clarity, and is sealed to avoid the nastiness of equality-over-polymorphism.

Comment: Is there a to user `IdPair` rather than `Tuple<int,int>`?

Comment: @Brian: Yes, the equality is different. You could use `Tuple<int, int>` and a custom `IEqualityComparer<Tuple<int, int>>` but it'll be about as much code, and it isn't as clear in terms of the meaning: here we're being very specific about what the two values are... they aren't just *any* two ints.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks, I missed that the pair was unordered.